# I cannot run the correct code on Visual Studio 2022 Community. How to fix it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version, c#-to-vb.net

I wrote an WinForm application work as an anlogue clock in C#. It worked smoothly and showed me the correct time. Then I tried to write the same analogue clock but in VB.There was no error on my code but VS throws an error like "Visual Studio cannot start debugging... ...Debug\VBAnalogueClock.exe is missing". What does VS mean by that? What should I get from this message? Shouldn't VS create this missing exe file when I start my project for the first time?

Comment: At a guess, I would suggest checking the project properties and the Debug tab. For the majority of projects this would be set to *Start Project*.

Comment: Have you checked whether the specified file is actually there or not? The file actually being missing and VS saying it's missing when it's not are two very different things, so you need to be clear about what problem you actually need to solve.

Comment: Ensure that you've enabled [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). Then, in VS menu, click: `Tools`. Select `Options...`. Expand `Projects and Solutions`.  Select `Build and Run`. Set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Normal` (or "Detailed"). Then Build (or Rebuild) your project. In VS menu click `Build`. Then select `Rebuild Solution`.